# How to create a real number generator whose value is persistent between kernel restarts?

Tags: functions, random

Suppose I have a function

```
f[x_] := RandomReal[]
```

If I set `x_=2` and `f[2]=.2134..`, I want `f[2]` to always equal `.2134..`.

Similarly, if I set `x=.5` and `f[.5]=.7654...` I want `f[.5]` to always equal `.7654`.

**Edit:** However when I reenter my code. The output is always different.

I couldn't find any documentation of Mathematica that can make this possible?

**Edit 2:** How do I make the values persistent between kernel restarts?

Comment: [`Functions That Remember Values They Have Found`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TransformationRulesAndDefinitions.html#202640595)

Comment: `f[x_] := SeedRandom[1]; RandomReal[]` ?

Comment: Use `SeedRandom` prior to `RandomReal` so each session uses the same starting state for the random generator.

Comment: @BobHanlon `SeedRandom` will only work if you're careful to do all the initial evaluations in the same order each session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The technique is known as memoization:

```
f[x_] := f[x] = RandomReal[]
f[.5]
(* 0.417073 *)
f[.5]
(* 0.417073 *)
```

Edit in response to comment:

One way to keep the results between kernel restarts is to save them in a file:

```
Save["SomeFileName", f]
```

Then, after restart:

```
<< SomeFileName
```

Comment: When I reenter my code the output is different. How do we make it permenant?

Comment: What do you mean by "permanent"? Persistent between kernel restarts?

Comment: Yes, persistent between kernal restarts.